# Running mapreduce wordcount (Java code) on multi node cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to run wordcount java program on hadoop multinode cluster using eclipse (which worked fine with single node cluster but not working in multinode). I am getting back following info

> INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
>   16/04/24 21:30:46 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
 {
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/sam/"));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/wc-output"));

job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

}

}
*

I Think there is something wrong with the paths.
I am running this code at master end

Answer (score 0):

Does the command

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/sam/
```

work ?

Comment: Try 
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hduser/sam/
if it works then we are probably giving the wrong port. 
Check  if the namenode process running on the node.